# Standards for using '#' with css hex colors?

Tags: css, coldfusion

What is the standard for using `#` with CSS hex colors? Can it be left off? (It seems to work without the `#`). Is it different depending on whether it is in a .css file vs inline? What about inside ColdFusion, where `#` is used for defining variables?

Comment: If you don't want to use hex/RGBA values, you can try color names that browsers support - http://www.crockford.com/wrrrld/color.html

Comment: Validate it and find out.

Comment: It works without the octothorp but produces a different colour.  Try it and see.

Comment: You can also use RGB values. The big question, however, is why you are worried about CSS being mixed with ColdFusion variables. This leads me to think you are using CSS inline with your HTML code, which is bad practice.

Comment: A hash in CF doesn't define variables, it is used as a marker for embedding an expression (which can thus output the values of simple variables, functions, or other logic). A literal `#` can be obtained by escaping it, as `##`.

Comment: Do you have a particular place were you think you will be mixing cfml and CSS at the same time?

Comment: I started at a new company, they do it both ways. Nix, that won't do. Cimmanon, it seems to validate in my browsers, but I'm looking for a STANDARD, or a reason to have a local shop standard. Dan, I'll try that, if true it would be a reason to have a standard coding practice. Scott, not practical, and bad practice or not, it's done frequently. :-P. Peter, sorry, I used incorrect terminology, yes I'm aware it can be escaped with another #. The problem some guys here stated was in copying from css into inline cfm, they'd forget to add the extra #, and that's why they like not having it at all.

Comment: Strictly in terms of [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#numerical), they say nothing about the `#` sign being optional and [CSS does not validate](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) without it.

Comment: It's less the terminology (though that is important) and more the understanding; there's been some recent questions on SO about where hash needs to be used in CFML, so just a case of trying to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks Peter, and everyone, for all the replies.

Answer (score 3):

In the past I have used a double # if he style was inline inside of a CFOUTPUT tag.

Example:

`<ul>
<cfoutput query="myquery">
<li><a href="somepage.cfm" style="color:##somevarLinkColor#;">#somevar#</a></li>
</cfoutput>
</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this link](http://css.wikidot.com/colors) to know how the color system works and why using only digits also works. I don't see how you will mess up with a # in your code, since that's always going to be part of your style attribute and also will be within "", thus completely non conflicting with the CF code.

Comment: It could conflict with CF code if using inline styles on elements that are inside of a `cfoutput` block.

Comment: This page does not show how hex numbers can be used in css without a #. :-( In a .css file you do not use quotes around a hex color value. And the reason I wanted an official standard is because in our shop there are coders who put the # and ones who don't, and we want to decide which way to do it shop-wide from now on.